# How to save database connection information when using `psql`?

Tags: postgresql, connectivity, psql

I am learning to use `psql` to work with a postgres database on linux.

I can connect using a long connection string, for example by running:

`psql postgresql://myusername:mypassword@localhost:5433/dbname`

However, I would like to save the details of my connection string somewhere, to simplify the command to connect to the database.

I've added the parameters to `~/.pgpass`, and I've also changed the environment variables `PGDATABSE`, `PGHOST`, `PGPORT`, and `PGUSER`.  However, I'm not sure how to tell `psql` to source connection information from either `~/.pgpass` or the environment variables.  When I just type `psql` I get an error, and I can tell from the details of the error that it is trying to connect using default parameters, like port 5432 instead of my specific port.

So how to I tell `psql` to use the parameters in `~/.pgpass` or the environment variables?  Or more broadly, how can I save my connection information to simplify the command to connect in the future?

Comment: Is the [service file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html) maybe what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the comment from @a_horse_with_no_name:

Enter the details in `~/.pg_service.conf`, for example:

```
#comment
[myconnection]
host=localhost
port=5432
user=myuser
dbname=mydb
password=mypassword
```

Then set a `PGSERVICE` environment variable specifying which connection to use

```
echo PGSERVICE=myconnection
```

Then simply entering `psql` should make the connection.